# NSURL breaking port string with colon

Tags: ios, escaping, nsurl

I'm trying to add a base url for my networking code, the problem is that this URL gets broken when passing to the `URLWithString:relativeToURL:` method. This URL has the port i'm using, however, after calling the described, the URL is wrong, not including my current port number. I think this is a problem with percent escapers, but i've tried some methods to solve this problem without success.

Here is my code:

```
// absolute string returns a url a with broken path
[[NSURL URLWithString:@"api/whatever" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"193.178.0.99:9000"]] absoluteString]
// printed absolute path 193.173.0.99:///api/whatever
```

Other tried approaches:

```
NSString *baseURLString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)@"193.178.0.99:9000",NULL,(CFStringRef)@":",kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
[[NSURL URLWithString:@"api/whatever" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURLString]]
// Printed path : 193.173.0.99%3A8000/api/whatever, this path is still not working, although i have the percent escape set.

NSString *baseURLString = [@"193.173.0.99:8000" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// ... The same final code from above.
// Printed -> the very same first result.
```

EDIT : From the comment above the `URLWithString:relativeToURL:` : "These methods expect their string arguments to contain any percent escape codes that are necessary."

Does anybody have a solution to this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - the "double dot" character (`:`) is called a "colon".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the solution is pretty simple... just add the scheme.

Something like this:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://193.178.0.99:9000"];
NSString *absoluteString = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"api/whatever" relativeToURL:baseURL] absoluteString];

// Prints => http://193.178.0.99:9000/api/whatever
```

Answer (score 3):

That behavior is actually quite understandable (from an RFC point of view): the `relativeToURL` part is expected to be a full-fledged URL root, **including the URL scheme**.

So here in your example, as you didn't provide an `http://` scheme or similar, `193.178.0.99` is considered to be the scheme — like it would be `http` or `https` or `ftp` or `tel` or `mailto` — and the `9000` port considered to be the `host` part of your URL (but as `9000` is probably not a valid host according to the RFC, it's probably why you have the warning by the way)

In a way, `193.178.0.99:9000` is interpreted in a similar manner a phone-number URL `tel:1-541-754-3010` or a mail URL `mailto:john.doe@nowhere.com` would; the `:` separating the URL scheme from the host, not separating the host from the port.

---

To solve this, simply include the URL scheme (like `http` or `https` or whatever the protocol you intend to use) in the `relativeToURL` parameter:

```
[[NSURL URLWithString:@"api/whatever"
        relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://193.178.0.99:9000"]]
 absoluteString];                         // ^^^^^~~ this is the important part
```

---

*Note: as an alternate solution to build your URL, you could use the iOS7's `NSURLComponents` class to manipulate `NSURL` parts separately, that's another way to break down and build up URLs*